# Node.js Unit Testing request.post(...).send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am beginning to test the components of my node.js website using chai and mocha, but when I run npm test I get this error:

' TypeError: request.post(...).send is not a function'

This is the code in my test.js file:

```
    const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const app = require("./app.js");
const express = require("express");
const request = express();

describe("POST /register", () => {
  it("should register a new user and redirect to login page", (done) => {
    const user = {
      email: "johndoe@example.com",
      username: "johndoe",
      password: "password",
      userType: "user"
    };
    request.post("/register")
      .send(user)
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.equal(302);
        expect(res.header.location).to.equal("/login");
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

I am new to Node.js so I'm still understanding how unit tests are executed. any help would be a appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`request` is an Express router object. Rather than sending a request, `request.post("/register")` registers a path on that router.

What you actually want to do is send a request. Because Express is for creating servers, not sending requests, you'll have to use a different library. It seems that your code is trying to use [`supertest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest), which is a testing library that does send requests.

To use supertest instead, first install it with `npm i supertest`, then change

```
const request = express();
```

in your code to

```
const request = require('supertest');
```

Comment: I updated my code but it throws the error:
request.post is not a function
I tried to change the line to :
const request = require('supertest')(app);  to pass the instance to the superset but it's still the same issue

Comment: @Lex_X Are you sure that `app.js` is exporting the main router?

Comment: I believe it's not recognizing the server app.js file, I've required it as I have with other files using that method that have worked before

Comment: @Lex_X Odd. Can you provide the full error/traceback that you're getting? `send` certainly is a method of `request().post()` per the documentation, so it's weird that you'd get the same error.

Comment: As long as `app` is a router and `/register` is a real path it should work.

Comment: I've updated my test file so that it reads at the top:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('./app.js');
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  const { address, port } = server.address();
  console.log(`Server running at http://${address}:${port}/`);
});

```

but I get the error app.listen() is not a function, but the server should be listening for a connection?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `app.js`? It seems that you aren't exporting the router correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely because request is an instance of express() rather than a request library like supertest.

To fix this, you can replace request.post("/register") with a request using the supertest library like this:

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("./app.js");

describe("POST /register", () => {
  it("should register a new user and redirect to login page", (done) => {
    const user = {
      email: "johndoe@example.com",
      username: "johndoe",
      password: "password",
      userType: "user"
    };
    request(app)
      .post("/register")
      .send(user)
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.equal(302);
        expect(res.header.location).to.equal("/login");
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

For fetching the address, use the following syntax

```
const app = require('./app');
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  const { address, port } = server.address();
  console.log(`Server running at http://${address}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: The error I am now getting is:

TypeError: app.address is not a function

I believe it has something to do with not recognizing the app.js file where the server is?

Comment: `address` is a property of the server object that is returned by app.listen(), not a function.

Comment: Ah right, but If the error says that app.address is not a function when that has not been specified in my code, this is an issue with the server itself? Apologies for the repetition I'm getting my head around it

Comment: make sure that the server is instantiated by `app.listen`, only `app.listen` returns a server which has an address in it.

Comment: @AkashDathan I don't think the router needs to be listening. All it needs is for the routes to be configured.